# Conditional package import breaks the code Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, factory

In my app I am using `sembast` db and I'm trying to adapt the `AppDatabase` singleton class to be platform dependent and use `sambast_web` when app is running on the web.
I'm trying to use the same pattern I used for user location so I created:

1. A stub with a getter method.
2. An `abstract class AppDatabase` to have a conditional package import for the device and web packages when importing the stub , and in the class factory method returns the stub getter method.
3. A `class AppDatabaseDevice` and a `class AppDatabaseWeb` which both implement `AppDatabase`.

When running the app dough I get an error:

```
Compiler message:
lib/fixit_shop_app/database/app_database_switcher.dart:50:28: Error: Method not found: 'getAppDatabase'.
  factory AppDatabase() => getAppDatabase();
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
Failed to build bundle.
Error launching application on iPad (6th generation).
```

Now, it's quite strange as when writing the code for the abstract class factory it finds `getAppDatabase()` an throws no error.

After twiddling a bit with the code I nailed down the problem being the conditional import of the stub import.

If I import it without conditional import as

```
import 'package:fixit_shop_flutter/fixit_shop_app/database/app_database_stub.dart';
```

then I get no error, but then again I do need the conditional import..

Can you spot why conditional import is failing  for this class and works for the other?

As always thank you very much for your time and help.
These are the the AppDatabase methods:

## Stub:

```
import 'app_database_switcher.dart';

AppDatabase getAppDatabase() => throw UnsupportedError(
    'Cant get AppDatabase if not loading the right package');
```

## Abstract class:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:sembast/sembast.dart';

import 'app_database_stub.dart'
    if (dart.library.io) 'package:sembast/sembast.dart'
    if (dart.library.js) 'package:sembast_web/sembast_web.dart';

abstract class AppDatabase {
  // Singleton instance
  static final AppDatabase _singleton;

  // Singleton accessor
  static AppDatabase get instance => _singleton;

  // Completer is used for transforming synchronous code into asynchronous code.
  Completer<Database> _dbOpenCompleter;

  // A private constructor. Allows us to create instances of AppDatabase
  // only from within the AppDatabase class itself.
  // Sembast database object
  Database _database;
  // Database object accessor
  Future<Database> get database async {
//    // If completer is null, AppDatabaseClass is newly instantiated, so database is not yet opened
    return _dbOpenCompleter.future;
  }


  factory AppDatabase() => getAppDatabase();
}
```

And this are user location methods:

## Stub:

```
import 'package:fixit_shop_flutter/fixit_shop_app/platform_user_location/user_location_switcher.dart';

UserLocation getUserLocation() =>
    throw UnsupportedError('user_location_stub error');
```

## Abstract class:

```
import 'package:fixit_shop_flutter/fixit_shop_app/platform_user_location/user_location_stub.dart' // Version which just throws UnsupportedError
    if (dart.library.io) "package:fixit_shop_flutter/fixit_shop_app/platform_user_location/user_location_device.dart"
    if (dart.library.js) "package:fixit_shop_flutter/fixit_shop_app/platform_user_location/user_location_web.dart";

abstract class UserLocation {
  // methods to be used

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getPosition() async {
    Future<Map<String, dynamic>> position;
    return position;
  }

  factory UserLocation() => getUserLocation();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error. Indeed it was the conditional import. I was importing the diverse sembast packages instead of the device and web class implementations..

```
import 'package:fixit_shop_flutter/fixit_shop_app/database/app_database_stub.dart'
   if (dart.library.io) 'package:fixit_shop_flutter/fixit_shop_app/database/app_database_device.dart'
   if (dart.library.js) 'package:fixit_shop_flutter/fixit_shop_app/database/app_database_web.dart';
```